# Display on CSS, HTML and Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I tried to search something of similar but didn't found.

I have two buttons. If I click one of them i want hide some div but it doesn't work. When i open the page the div d2 and d3 are hidden and it's okay. When i try to click one button it clicks and do nothing.
Exists another way to do what i want do?
Am I doing something wrong?

```
<head><title>Aggiungi Studi e Lavori</title>
<script type='text/javascript'>

 function Funz1()
    {
        document.getElementById("d1").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("d2").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("d3").style.display = "block";

    }


function Funz2()
    {
        document.getElementById("d1").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("d2").style.display = "block";
        document.getElementById("d3").style.display = "none";

    }

function checkForm3()
 {
 // Controllo che tutti i campi  della registrazione vengano inseriti
    if(document.registration_form.luogo.value == '' ||
   document.registration_form.titolo.value == '' || 
   document.registration_form.anno.value == '' ||
   )
{
    alert('Inserire tutti i dati contrassegnati con un asterisco');
    return false;
}
// Se arriviamo qui va tutto bene
return true;
}

function checkForm4()
{
// Controllo che tutti i campi  della registrazione vengano inseriti
if(document.registration_form.luogo2.value == '' ||
   document.registration_form.ruolo.value == '' || 
   document.registration_form.anno2.value == '' ||
   )
{
    alert('Inserire tutti i dati contrassegnati con un asterisco');
    return false;
}
// Se arriviamo qui va tutto bene
return true;
}
</script>

<meta charset="utf-8"> 
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" 

href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
 <script 
 src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"> 
</script>
 <script 
src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"> 
 </script>
 </head>
<body>

<br>
<div id="d1">

<button type="button" onclick="Funz1()" >Aggiungi Esperienza 
Lavorativa</button>              
 <button type="button" onclick="Funz2()" > Aggiungi Esperienza di 
Studio</button> 

</div>



<div id="d2" style= display:none>
<br><form name='studio_form' action='Esperienze.php' method='post' 
 onsubmit='return checkForm3()' >
        <div class='row'>

<div class='form-group col-xs-12 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-lg-6'>            
<label for='titolo'>Titolo</label>
<input type='text' name='titolo'>
</div>

<div class='form-group col-xs-12 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-lg-6'>            
<label for='anno'>Anno</label>
<input type='text' name='anno'>
</div>

<div class='form-group col-xs-12 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-lg-6'>            
<label for='luogo'>Luogo</label>
<input type='date' name='luogo'>
</div>



<div class='form-group col-xs-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-lg-12'>                
<input name='submit' type='submit' value='Aggiungi'>     
</div>      

</div>                
</form>
</div>








<div id="d3" style= display:none>
<form name='lavoro_form' action='Esperienze.php' method='post' 
onsubmit='return 
checkForm4()' disabled>
        <div class='row'>

<div class='form-group col-xs-12 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-lg-6'>            
<label for='ruolo'>Ruolo</label>
<input type='text' name='ruolo'>
</div>

<div class='form-group col-xs-12 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-lg-6'>            
<label for='anno2'>Anno</label>
<input type='text' name='anno2'>
</div>

<div class='form-group col-xs-12 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-lg-6'>            
<label for='luogo2'>Luogo</label>
<input type='date' name='luogo2'>
</div>



<div class='form-group col-xs-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-lg-12'>                
<input name='submit' type='submit' value='Aggiungi'>     
</div>      

</div>                
</form>
</div>

 </body>   



</html>
```

Comment: Syntax error in function checkForm4().  if (condition1 || ) {..}

Comment: not just the checkForm4, all checks are finishing the `if` with `||`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are finishing your `if()` with `||`. So that code will expect another condition and not a closing tag.

```html
<head><title>Aggiungi Studi e Lavori</title>
<script type='text/javascript'>

 function Funz1()
    {
        document.getElementById("d1").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("d2").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("d3").style.display = "block";

    }


function Funz2()
    {
        document.getElementById("d1").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("d2").style.display = "block";
        document.getElementById("d3").style.display = "none";

    }

function checkForm3()
 {
 // Controllo che tutti i campi  della registrazione vengano inseriti
    if(document.registration_form.luogo.value == '' ||
   document.registration_form.titolo.value == '' || 
   document.registration_form.anno.value == ''
   )
{
    alert('Inserire tutti i dati contrassegnati con un asterisco');
    return false;
}
// Se arriviamo qui va tutto bene
return true;
}

function checkForm4()
{
// Controllo che tutti i campi  della registrazione vengano inseriti
if(document.registration_form.luogo2.value == '' ||
   document.registration_form.ruolo.value == '' || 
   document.registration_form.anno2.value == ''
   )
{
    alert('Inserire tutti i dati contrassegnati con un asterisco');
    return false;
}
// Se arriviamo qui va tutto bene
return true;
}
</script>

<meta charset="utf-8"> 
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" 

href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
 <script 
 src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"> 
</script>
 <script 
src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"> 
 </script>
 </head>
<body>

<br>
<div id="d1">

<button type="button" onclick="Funz1()" >Aggiungi Esperienza 
Lavorativa</button>              
 <button type="button" onclick="Funz2()" > Aggiungi Esperienza di 
Studio</button> 

</div>



<div id="d2" style= display:none>
<br><form name='studio_form' action='Esperienze.php' method='post' 
 onsubmit='return checkForm3()' >
        <div class='row'>

<div class='form-group col-xs-12 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-lg-6'>            
<label for='titolo'>Titolo</label>
<input type='text' name='titolo'>
</div>

<div class='form-group col-xs-12 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-lg-6'>            
<label for='anno'>Anno</label>
<input type='text' name='anno'>
</div>

<div class='form-group col-xs-12 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-lg-6'>            
<label for='luogo'>Luogo</label>
<input type='date' name='luogo'>
</div>



<div class='form-group col-xs-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-lg-12'>                
<input name='submit' type='submit' value='Aggiungi'>     
</div>      

</div>                
</form>
</div>








<div id="d3" style= display:none>
<form name='lavoro_form' action='Esperienze.php' method='post' 
onsubmit='return 
checkForm4()' disabled>
        <div class='row'>

<div class='form-group col-xs-12 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-lg-6'>            
<label for='ruolo'>Ruolo</label>
<input type='text' name='ruolo'>
</div>

<div class='form-group col-xs-12 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-lg-6'>            
<label for='anno2'>Anno</label>
<input type='text' name='anno2'>
</div>

<div class='form-group col-xs-12 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-lg-6'>            
<label for='luogo2'>Luogo</label>
<input type='date' name='luogo2'>
</div>



<div class='form-group col-xs-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-lg-12'>                
<input name='submit' type='submit' value='Aggiungi'>     
</div>      

</div>                
</form>
</div>

 </body>
```

PS: did you try using the developer tools in the browser, since that throws you an error hinting you `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token )` with a reference to the line where the error was.

Answer (score 0):

Idk if this could be causing the problem but you have an opening script tag that looks like this

```
<script
```

it is right below the link to your stylesheet

```
<link rel="stylesheet" 

href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```